# How to use ext4 inline_data to store empty directories?

Tags: files, filesystems, ext4

How can I use [ext4's inline_data feature](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) to store empty directories?
It seems like inline_data works only with small files, or the directories store a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

You need `e2fsprogs` 1.43 or later, and you need to create a file system with the `inline_data` feature enabled, and inodes with at least 256 bytes:

```
mke2fs -t ext4 -O inline_data ...
```

(if `mke2fs` complains about the inodes being too small, add `-I 256`).

Directories will then use inline data transparently, as long as the data they need to store fits inside their inode. `debugfs`’s `stat` command will show inode data which looks like

```
Inode: 12   Type: directory    Mode:  0755   Flags: 0x10000000
Generation: 3089239889    Version: 0x00000000:00000002
User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 60
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 3   Blockcount: 0
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x5bcb759e:a9872534 -- Sat Oct 20 20:36:14 2018
 atime: 0x5bcb759e:a9872534 -- Sat Oct 20 20:36:14 2018
 mtime: 0x5bcb759e:a9872534 -- Sat Oct 20 20:36:14 2018
crtime: 0x5bcb759e:a9872534 -- Sat Oct 20 20:36:14 2018
Size of extra inode fields: 32
Extended attributes:
  system.data (0)
Inode checksum: 0x68fa51fe
Size of inline data: 60
```

This is for a directory containing one other directory; as you can see, it stores 60 bytes of inline data and has no extent.

Comment: Note that ext4 does not shrink directories, so inline_data is only used for small files and dies until they grow larger than will fit into the inode.